# Error with 3D Asymptote graphs in Latex

Tags: miktex, texmaker, 3d, asymptote

I'm trying to use 3D graphs with Asymptote, runing on Windows 10 and using Miktex and Texmaker. I found what it seemed to be like a nice example on Overleaf, but it won't work. Here's the code:

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage[inline]{asymptote}  
\usepackage[paper=a4paper,hmargin=2cm,vmargin=2.5cm]{geometry}  
\usepackage{parskip}  
\setlength{\columnsep}{3em}

\begin{document}

\begin{asy}  
settings.render=0;  
import graph3;  
size(0,200);  
size3(200,IgnoreAspect);  
currentprojection=orthographic(4,6,3);  
real x(real t) {return cos(2pi*t);}  
real y(real t) {return sin(2pi*t);}  
real z(real t) {return t;}  
path3 p=graph(x,y,z,0,2.7,operator ..);  
draw(p,Arrow3);  
scale(true);  
xaxis3(XZ()*"$x$",Bounds,red,InTicks(Label,2,2));  
yaxis3(YZ()*"$y$",Bounds,red,InTicks(beginlabel=false,Label,2,2));  
zaxis3(XZ()*"$z$",Bounds,red,InTicks);  
\end{asy}

\end{document}
```

Texmaker throws the following error warnings: `Support package l3kernel too old`, `Support package l3packages too old`, `media9 error: support outdated`. I already tried downloading these packages from the MikTex package manager (with admin priviliges), installing them, and then refreshing FNDB and updating formats from the MikTex settings (again with admin priviliges), but it didn't work.

At this point I am clueless in how to proceed. If someone could help me out on getting the 3D Asymptote runnning I would very much appreciate it.

Comment: Run the update manager in user mode and check for updates.

Comment: @Gugumatz This compiles perfectly. You should know that asymptote requires a triple compilation LaTeX -> Asymptote -> LaTeX

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I can confirm this too. Users tend to forget to compile ASY and they assume it's done automatically.

Comment: @ChenStatsYu You don't  get an error "Support package l3kernel too old" if you forget to run asy. This indicates that something is not uptodate and the probable cause is that the user didn't  realize that one should also check for updates as user and not only as admin.

Comment: Tried sinchronizing first from the Miktex Package Manager, both as admin and user. That didn't work. Then tried performing a Miktex update, which didn't seem like a good idea because the involved packages were going to be uninstalled. I did it anyway and the update crashed half-way through, Texmaker was then not compiling previously working documents. I uninstalled and re-installed Miktex and everything went surprisingly smooth: 3d Asymptote graphs are now compiling. Thank you all for your comments and suggestions!

PS: I was using the triple compilation LaTeX -> Asymptote -> LaTeX.